# XST - using output from call-template as return value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Suppose i have a template `foo` which can output something given a parameter. Now I want to use that output as a parameter to my other template, `loop` so I can loop the output a certain number of times. I have tried something along the way of

```
    <xsl:call-template name="loop">
        <xsl:with-param name="times" select="someParam"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="output">
            <xsl:call-template name="foo">
                <xsl:with-param name="type" select="something"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
```

In other words, `output` should now contain the output from the call to `foo`. Both `loop` and `foo` work fine independantely but it seems like I can't nest them this way. How should I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a working example of your provided code and for some recommendations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The problem is in the code you haven't shown to us. This is a correct way to chain/pipe templates, although I would not recommend it** (see at the end of this answer),

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="loop">
        <xsl:with-param name="times" select="3"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="output">
            <xsl:call-template name="foo">
                <xsl:with-param name="pN" select="5"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="loop">
  <xsl:param name="times" select="1"/>
  <xsl:param name="output" select="2"/>

  <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($times > 0)">
       <xsl:value-of select="$output"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:call-template name="loop">
        <xsl:with-param name="times" select="$times -1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="output" select="2*$output"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="foo">
  <xsl:param name="pN" select="1"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="2*$pN"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML (not used), produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
80
```

**Stylistic recommendation**:

Try to avoid chaining templates in this way as this results in unreadable and unmaintainable code.

**It is much better to obtain the intermediate results into (properly named) variables**. Not only is the code more readable and maintainable this way, but any intermediate result can be re-used multiple times without the need to re-evaluate it.

**Here is the same transformation but factored to meet the recommended stylistic requirements**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="vTwice">
    <xsl:call-template name="twice">
      <xsl:with-param name="pN" select="5"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:call-template name="loop">
        <xsl:with-param name="pTtimes" select="3"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pN" select="$vTwice"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="loop">
  <xsl:param name="pTtimes" select="1"/>
  <xsl:param name="pN" select="2"/>

  <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($pTtimes > 0)">
       <xsl:value-of select="$pN"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:call-template name="loop">
        <xsl:with-param name="pTtimes" select="$pTtimes -1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pN" select="2*$pN"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="twice">
  <xsl:param name="pN" select="1"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="2*$pN"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```