# is variable instantiated at declaration

Tags: xml, xslt

I am newbie in XSLT so I need some clarification.
In many of the posts here like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007658/xst-using-output-from-call-template-as-return-value) one for example I see that when we call a template into the body of the variable, the template should be processed, despite of we haven't referenced that variable in our code.
I did test to check it for myself. This is the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="var">
        <xsl:call-template name="my_template"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$var"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="my_template">
    <tag>
        <xsl:value-of select="103"/>
    </tag>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>103
```

Please note `103` at the end, and please note that the tag `<tag>` is not present at the output. Why?
Next I remove this line `<xsl:value-of select="$var"/>` from the file and do transformation again. Now the output is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

`103` has gone. It seems to me that the template `my_template` has never been processed. So if the variable is declared but not referenced the value of that variable is not processed? Please shed some light on this mater. And why the tag `tag` does not appear at the output?

Thank you, and please excuse my poor English. I hope you get my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> please note that the tag  is not present at the output. Why?

The tag is not present because when you do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$var"/>
```

you are only outputting the [string-value](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value) of the `$var` variable. You will get a different result with:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$var"/>
```

which will output the entire variable.

---

> Next I remove this line `<xsl:value-of select="$var"/>` from the file ...  It seems to me that the template `my_template` has never been processed.

It may have been and it may have not - that's up to your processor. It may decide it's not needed and save itself the trouble.